# Coverting and grouping an string array in a tree object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var exampeInclude= [
  "Product",
  "Group",
  "Product.Tax",
  "Product.ProductUnit",
  "Product.Variant.Original",
  "Product.Variant.Original.Tax",
  "Product.Variant.Original.ProductUnit"
];
```

I need to get the following structure from this array:

```
 [
    {
        "Product": {
            "includes": [
                {
                    "Tax": {
                        "includes": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ProductUnit": {
                        "includes": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Variant": {
                        "includes": [
                            {
                                "Original": {
                                    "includes": [] //...
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Group": {
            "includes": []
        }
    }
]
```

Kind of a tree structure. But I do not get the right solution. Everything I try ends in wired foreach that are soon not debugable. The best I have so far is a simple reduce function, but how can I implement the `split('.')` into this? Do I need some recursion?

The best I have right now:

```
var hist = exampeInclude.reduce(function (prev, item) { 
  if( item in prev ) prev[item] ++; 
  else prev[item] = 1; 
  return prev;  
}, {});
```

(I know it's not much, it simply counts. But I think `reduce` is a good way to start)

Comment: this is very specific, it might be usefull to formalize with words what you want :
parse array of string paths, build a tree object from the paths but each object will contain an 'includes' child array which contains sub object, is it exact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a tree from the path, and finally add intermediate 'includes' array

```
function buildFromPath(tree, pathVar){
  var a = pathVar.split('.'),
     parent = tree;
  for(var i = 0, max = a.length; i < max; i++){
     var n = a[i];
     if(!(n in parent))   parent[n] = {};
     parent = parent[n];
  }
}
var exampeInclude= [
  "Product",
  "Group",
  "Product.Tax",
  "Product.ProductUnit",
  "Product.Variant.Original",
  "Product.Variant.Original.Tax",
  "Product.Variant.Original.ProductUnit"
],
tree = {};
for(var i = 0, max = exampeInclude.length; i < max; i++){
   buildFromPath(tree, exampeInclude[i]);
}
// normally here you should have a tree structure
// like {Product:{Tax:{},ProductUnit:{},Variant:{Original:{Tax:{},ProductUnit:{}}}},Group:{}}
// then you parse the tree and add format with intermediates
function formatObj(obj){
   var res = [];
   for(var name in obj){
     var o = obj[name];
     res.push(o);
     o.includes = formatObj(o);
   }
   return res;
}
var res = formatObj(tree);
```